# Did a former CIA accountant testify that Lee Harvey Oswald was a CIA employee?

Tags: united-states, cia, jfk

[Harvey and Lee](http://harveyandlee.net/) is a web-site that documents some [conspiracy theories about the death of John F. Kennedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Kennedy_assassination_conspiracy_theories).

In particular, it contains [a purported transcript](http://harveyandlee.net/Wilcott/Wil_full.htm) of the testimony of a 1978 former CIA accountant, James B. Wilcott:

> Mr. Wilcott. Well, it was my understanding that Lee Harvey Oswald was an employee of the agency and was an agent of the agency.
>
> Mr. Goldsmith. What do you mean by the term "agent"?
>
> Mr. Wilcott. That he was a regular employee, receiving
> a full-time salary for agent work for doing CIA operational
> work.

The site claim is currently (June 17, 2021) one of the top posts in [r/conspiracy](https://np.reddit.com/r/conspiracy/comments/o1o17u/in_1978_former_cia_accountant_james_b_wilcott).

Did a former CIA accountant testify that Lee Harvey Oswald was a CIA employee?

Comment: Please provide more information such as where the testimony took place and why it was given

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The testimony is available from [archives.gov](https://www.archives.gov/files/research/jfk/releases/docid-32263407.pdf), apparently released in October 2017; it matches the testimony given in the claim.

In it, James Wilcott testifies that, while working at the CIA, he heard rumours from several colleagues that Oswald worked for the CIA, he was told the cryptonym (code name) purportedly of Oswald, but he didn't see any evidence to support the rumour.

Comment: If what you write in the second paragraph is true, then the claim in the question is untrue.

Comment: @DJClayworth agree with you on this one.  While the testimony the website uses as evidence of the claim certainly exists, it's not the damning proof that LHO worked for the CIA that OP's claimant says it is.  It's one accountant that heard a rumor from another guy that LHO was on their payroll.